# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing the following issue :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

I am using httpclient 4.5 jar. Could you please let me know how to resolve it?

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] {"TLSv1" }, null,
                       SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

my pom.xml contains the following dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The class is actually there in the JAR file. You have mentioned your dependency as 'provided', ensure the JAR is available in the CLASSPATH at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory and there was appropriate dependency in Maven.

The reason of the problem in our case was tika-app, when we changed it to tica-core the problem was solved. The part commented below we replaced with the part above:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>-->
```